# React router private route is accessing routes that it shouldn't access

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This application have login/signup account, and a google oauth account.

My issue is telling private route to **not access** the authenticate routes like dashboard/edit profile, etc. **Upon googleOauth logout**.

For example this navbar does exactly what i want, but this logic does't work in private route component.

its this logic

```
props.isAuthenticated === true || props.googleAccount != ""
```

so if isAuthenticated(regular account) is true show these authenticated nav buttons, or if googleAccount logged in, show authenticated nav buttons. I want to implement this same logic in private route but its not guarding any of the routes.

*props.googleAccount is just a string(googleId)*

*props.isAuthenticated is a boolean*

**Router.tsx**

```
const user = props.currentUser.user ? props.currentUser.user : "";
    const googleId = props.currentUser && props.currentUser.user ? props.currentUser.user.googleId : null;
    console.log("router", user);
    console.log("dsdsdsds", props.googleAccount);
    return props.hasError ? (
        <div>Error</div>
    ) : (
        <Router history={history}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid justify="space-between" container={true}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                            TypeScript React App
                        </Typography>
                        <Grid item={true}>
                            {props.isAuthenticated === true || props.googleAccount != "" ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to="/"
                                        >
                                            Home
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                            }}
                                            to="/dashboard"
                                        >
                                            Dashboard
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                            }}
                                            to={{
                                                pathname: `/${user.id}/likes`,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Your Likes
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to="/editProfile"
                                        >
                                            Edit Profile
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Notification
                                        userId={user.id}
                                        id={id}
                                        handleClose={handleClose}
                                        open={open}
                                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                        handleNotificationClick={handleNotificationClick}
                                        title={"Notifications"}
                                    />
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to={{
                                                pathname: `/profile/${user.username}`,
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            Profile
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button style={{ color: "#fff" }} onClick={props.logOut}>
                                        Logout
                                    </Button>
                                </Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to="/"
                                        >
                                            Home
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to="/register"
                                        >
                                            Sign Up
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button>
                                        <Link
                                            style={{
                                                color: "#fff",
                                                fontWeight: "500",
                                                textDecoration: "none",
                                            }}
                                            to="/login"
                                        >
                                            Log In
                                        </Link>
                                    </Button>
                                </Fragment>
                            )}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Landing} {...props} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route path="/emailConfirmation" component={EmailConfirmation} {...props} />
                {/* <Route path='/resendEmailConfirmation'></Route> */}
                <Route path="/emailConfirmationSuccess/:userId/:token" component={EmailConfirmationSuccess} {...props} />
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/profile/:username" component={Profile} {...props} />
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/editProfile" component={EditProfile} {...props} />
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/:userId/likes" component={Likes} {...props} />
                <PrivateRoute exact={true} path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} {...props} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/post/:id" component={Post} {...props} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
```

**PrivateRoute.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (rest.isAuthenticated || rest.googleAccount != null ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login" }} />)} />
);
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be to do with this condition

```
rest.isAuthenticated || rest.googleAccount != null
```

this condition returns true even if rest.googleAccount is "" (empty string)

Comment: So what should i do instead ?

Comment: it depends on how  authentication is implemented in your project,if its working fine on  navbar you can use the same condition right?  props.isAuthenticated === true || props.googleAccount != ""  not (rest.isAuthenticated || rest.googleAccount != null) since props.isAuthenticated === true || props.googleAccount != ""  might be the one which fits your implementation

Comment: instead of checking for null ,check for empty string for googleAccount prop

Comment: yeah been working on this for some hours, i keep getting redirected to the login screen, something is not right, either the private route is not reading the rest prop right away or something else. Will accept as answer, if i come up with a solution that solves my dilama . I will post it as an answer.